# get the value of a query to be part of another query

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to use the value of signerID to be part of the where clause in another query, but getting red underline with error: "delegate does not take 1 argument". Basically I want to use the value of signerID query (value = 15) in the where clause of the query allDepartments. Here's the code:

```
 using (dbPSREntities10 myEntities = new dbPSREntities10())
        {
            int theStatus = Convert.ToInt32(ddlChangeStatus.SelectedValue);
            string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

            var signerID = (from refAuthSigner in myEntities.refAuthSigners.Where(x => x.NetworkUsername == userName)
                            select new
                                  {
                                      refAuthSignerID = refAuthSigner.refAuthSignerID
                                  }); <---- here I should have the value 15

            var allDepartments = (from tbProject in myEntities.tbProjects.Where(x => x.refAuthSignerID == signerID)<-- and I want to use the value of signerID (15) here
```

Is this way off? I can hardcode 15 in place of signerID in the where clasue and everything works fine. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to join tables on singer id:

```
var allDepartments = 
    from p in myEntities.tbProjects
    join s in myEntities.refAuthSigners
        on p.refAuthSignerID equals s.refAuthSignerID
    where s.NetworkUsername == userName
    select p;
```

This query will select only those project which have singer id equal to id of singer with provided name.

---

Of course, you can do all in two queries - get id by first query, and them use id in second query:

```
int singerId = myEntities.refAuthSigners
                         .Where(s => s.NetworkUsername == userName)
                         .Select(s => s.refAuthSignerID)
                         .FirstOrDefault(); // execute first query

if (singerId == 0)
    return; // singer not found

// build second query
var allDepartments = myEntities.tbProjects
                               .Where(p => p.refAuthSignerID == signerID);
```

Comment: Is this linq to sql? Am I using linq to entities? Whatever my syntax is called makes no sense to me and yours is great knowing SQL. Do you have a recommendation one over the other?

Comment: The bottom code is perfect. Thanks! Although my variable is "signerId" not "singerId" ;) it's tough to see the difference.

Comment: @user1431633 join is better, because it takes single database query